# importing cv2 error

Tags: pi-3b+, opencv, piface

Hey i have working on 2Rpi One is working fine but the other one is giving me this error.

**ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_fetch_add_8**

while i am running my face detection code but when i am preloading **LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 thonny &** it from my cmd then it is working fine and giving me result.
I want to know why is this happening and how i can make it normal so that i only have to compile from Thonny IDE not to start from cmd.

Comment: How to did you installed it?

Comment: This is a general programming problem and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com/.